# Clippath not responsive in Google Chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I am currently coding a onepage (with fullpage.js) and want to use clippaths to match the [design](http://epvpimg.com/4d0peab).

In any browser (even Chrome on PC) the clippaths work just fine. But if I try it on my friends' smartphones with the Google Chrome App (S8+, S9+, Huawei Mate 20 Lite, OnePlus 5+) the clippaths don't work as expected (Picture links below).

- [Expected](http://epvpimg.com/bKbfaab) (working in Firefox)
- [Current](http://epvpimg.com/G6tufab) (Google Chrome App)

I wrote the following code:

```css
.triangle-bottom__orange {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #f0932b;
  height: 20vh;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="page2 section">
  <div class="triangle-bottom__orange"></div>
</div>
```

[Live-Demo](https://mypenink.com/)

Many thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Tested out yesterday with Safari running on an iPhone, same problem but way much worse.

Comment: Does anybody have an answer?